# How AppCheck uses AppAttest?

Tags: ios, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-app-check

On iOS, Firebase's AppCheck uses Apple's DeviceCheck/AppAttest provider to authenticate server requests from users.
AppAttest provides many ways to legitimize clients, my question is:  Does AppCheck implement them all? And if not, where can I see how AppCheck actually uses AppAttest?

Thank you for your attention!

Answer (score 1):

Let me provide a brief description of how Firebase App Check uses App Attest:

- Initially Firebase SDK creates and certifies a key pair pretty much
  following the first steps from [Establishing Your App’s Integrity](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/devicecheck/establishing_your_app_s_integrity)
  article.
- The App Attest attestation data is sent to Firebase server
  where it is verified (see more details on the verification in
  following [Validating Apps That Connect to Your Server](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/devicecheck/validating_apps_that_connect_to_your_server) article). In
  exchange to the valid attestation, the server passes to the SDK:

  - the
    attestation artifact encrypted with a key generated by Firebase for
    your app. The artifact contains the app instance data including the
    App Attest Key ID to generate assertions later.
  - a Firebase App Check
    token that can be attached to requests to certify their validity. The
    Firebase App Check token is relatively short-lived. Its expiration
    time can be configured in the Firebase console for your app needs.
- When the Firebase App Check token expires it is refreshed using an
  App Attest assertion generated based on the attestation artifact, App
  Attest key ID and a very short lived challenge requested from the
  Firebase server.

Also note that our SDKs are open source, and you can see the implementation details in our [GitHub repository](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk). Most of the App Attest implementation can be found in [this directory](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/tree/master/FirebaseAppCheck/Sources/AppAttestProvider).